# How to get selected row values from a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am converting a HTML table to an array and passing it in to a controller for inserting multiple rows. I am able to create the array, but the problem is it's creating a complete table array but I want to get the selected row `td` values only.

```
//function to convert HTML table to  array//
var HTMLtbl = {
    getData: function (table) {
        var data = [];
        table.find('tr').not(':first').each(function(rowIndex, r) {
            var cols = [];

            // I believe the main problem is here:
            $(this).find('td').each(function(colIndex, c) {
                cols.push($(this).text().trim());
            });
            data.push(cols);
        });
        return data;
    }
}

$(document).on('click', '#btnsave', function() {
    var data = HTMLtbl.getData($('#tblresult'));
    var parameters = {};
    parameters.array = data;

    var request =  $.ajax({
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "../Home/Save_SearchCarsDocs",        
        data: JSON.stringify(parameters)
    });
    request.done(function(msg) {
        alert("Row saved " + msg.d);
    });
```

Comment: How exactly do you know when a row is selected? Seeing your HTML would help a lot. Is there a checkbox or some other element in each row of the table?

Comment: You can use colIndex property to identify index of TD and can easily decide what to exclude. Or else if you want more appropriate solution, you can add a data attribute to TD to exclude that TD .. e.g. <td data-exclude="1"> .. and it can be used to exclude the target TD .. let me know if you need code for this solution

Answer (score 0):

You can try following...

```
    //function to convert HTML table to  array//
   var excludedTD_Index = [0,5,7]; // define what you want to exclude by index
    var HTMLtbl = {
        getData: function (table) {
            var data = [];
            table.find('tr').not(':first').each(function(rowIndex, r) {
                var cols = [];

                // I believe the main problem is here:
                $(this).find('td').each(function(colIndex, c) {
                    if(excludedTD_Index.indexOf(colIndex) >=0) // exclude TD
                    continue;
                    cols.push($(this).text().trim());
                });
                data.push(cols);
            });
            return data;
        }
    }

    $(document).on('click', '#btnsave', function() {
        var data = HTMLtbl.getData($('#tblresult'));
        var parameters = {};
        parameters.array = data;

        var request =  $.ajax({
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "../Home/Save_SearchCarsDocs",        
            data: JSON.stringify(parameters)
        });
        request.done(function(msg) {
            alert("Row saved " + msg.d);
        });
```

OR you can make it more managable if you can add following data to your TD tag

```
<td data-exclude="1"> 
...
```

after adding above data you can exclude those columns as following

```
 var HTMLtbl = {
        getData: function (table) {
            var data = [];
            table.find('tr').not(':first').each(function(rowIndex, r) {
                var cols = [];

                // I believe the main problem is here:
                $(this).find('td').each(function(colIndex, c) {
                    if($(this).data("exclude") == 1) // exclude TD
                    continue;
                    cols.push($(this).text().trim());
                });
                data.push(cols);
            });
            return data;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks  Rory McCrossan finally get my answer i am adding my solution below

```
     var CB=1;
var HTMLtbl =
    {
        getData: function (table) {
            var data = [];

            table.find('tr').not(':first').each(function (rowIndex, r) {
                if ($("#chk_" + CB).is(':checked'))
                    {
                    var cols = [];
                    $(this).find('td').each(function (colIndex, c) {                      
                        cols.push($(this).text().trim());     

                    });
                    data.push(cols);
                }
                CB++;
            });
            CB = 1;
            return data;

        }
    }
```